# Does paypal sandbox not actually "auto return" upon order completion?

Tags: paypal

I have sandbox paypal setup to auto return to my site once the order is complete. I've yet to throw anything live due to the fact when I do actually complete an order in sandbox paypal it stays on paypal's site and says

> You just made a payment of $$$$ USD
>
> Return To The Test Store

I have auto return set to yes and the return url set as well (its the url it send me to when I click the link)

If I click on the "return to the test store" link it then takes me to a paypal page that does redirect and does what I want.. Is this how it works on live? I need it to be when the order is complete it goes back to my site so I can right the order and order details and not have to rely on the user to click this button to create the order.

Answer (score 0):

PayPal sandbox works (almost) exactly as live payment. It's thought to create tests and simulate real payments before going live, as you're doing. Here you can find an [**official wizard**](https://devtools-paypal.com/integrationwizard/) to create Express Checkout button. It allows you to indicate a success page and an error page (both on your site) and download a library file (i.e. paypalfunctions.php, i.e. if you're using PHP file).

When user logs in and grants for payment, he's redirected back to your website (success page), where you actually confirm payment (by calling `ConfirmPayment` function in paypalfunctions.php), get money from his account and thanks him for shopping. If user instead clicks on "return to the test store", he's redirected to error page on your website (may be catalogue page or home page).

This is the classical Express Checkout Flow, as described [**here**](https://devtools-paypal.com/integrationwizard/ecpaypal/intro.php).

I suggest you to follow the wizard, download library files, setup your sandbox api credentials and make some tests. Hope it helps.

Comment: I have encrypted buttons working, I am passing a return url through it as well as setting the return url through the website preferences. I also have Payment Data Transfer working. The problem is its not auto returning immediately after the purchase is confirmed but only when I click the link it creates tied to "Return to the test store"

Comment: Can you paste your encrypted button here , so that we can try to complete a payment and see it redirects automatically or not?